# Is DRAKON Still in use Today?

Tags: spacecraft, operations, language, soviet-union

[DRAKON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON) is a Russian language standard programming interface which was created for the Soviet space program.  It had the added benefit of being a visual language, and possibly the first for the Soviet space program.

I wanted to find out if there are any space programs still using the language today?  Either new, or old equipment still functioning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Is it still in use today?

Considering the [sourceforge site for a DRAKON editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drakon-editor/) shows over 100 downloads this week and it was last updated June 1st, 2015 I'd say that project is active, which strongly suggests the language is still in use.

## Are there any space programs still using the language today?

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON):

> The work was finished in 1996 (3 years after the Buran project was officially closed), when an automated CASE programming system called "Grafit-Floks" was developed.
>
> This CASE is used since 1996 in many major space programs: an international project Sea Launch, Russian orbit insertion upper stage Fregat (Russian: Фрегат, frigate), upgraded heavy launch vehicle (carrier rocket) Proton-M, etc.

(CASE standing for [Computer Aided Software Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_software_engineering), basically the editor for developing in DRAKON)

Now the question becomes: do Fregat or Proton-M still fly?

As of 2012 Fregat was in [active production](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/fregat.html) for flight with 10+ stages produced per year.  I haven't found any reference to it no longer being used, and it appears to still be on offer on the [Arianespace Soyuz Launch Services](http://www.arianespace.com/launch-services-soyuz/soyuz-introduction.asp) page as of July 2015.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Proton_launches_%282010%E2%80%93present%29) lists 3 Proton-M launches so far in 2015, though the last one failed.

That gives at least two ongoing programs that use DRAKON.